# Summarizing data in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am still new to PostgreSQL and am hoping someone could help be optimize the following code for speed. The `hg100` table has 17 million records, `curstate` has 11 million, and getting any information related to it is painful so want to make sure I am coding optimally and correctly. This script does run, however , I get an error:

> ERROR:  GEOSUnaryUnion: TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid:
>   Self-intersection at or near point 5095.56885091
>   6240.45418185 at 537.56804091 62441.4540885
>   ********** Error **********

The first time I ran the code it took 1.5 hours to get that error message. To try and solve this issue I placed ST_MAKEVALID; it crashed again with the same error but it took 3.3 hours instead.

I am trying to get a summary of lang. The result will have 15 rows and the area within each according to disturbance state.

```
SELECT d.lang, st_area(st_union(st_intersection(st_makevalid(b.geom), st_makevalid(d.geom)))) / 10000 distbuf_area
     FROM p797.hg100 b, p797.ages d 
     WHERE st_intersects(b.geom,d.geom)
     AND b.hex_id in 
             (
              SELECT hex_id 
              FROM p797.curstate_20170120_100 
              WHERE disturbed = 1)
     GROUP BY lang;
```

Geoms and Hex_ID's are indexed. Hex_id is PK.

PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: What is the relations between the both tables?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand, again new, but one (ages) has 15 rows that encompass hg100. THe only relationship they have is spatial location

Comment: I ask because this ..FROM p797.hg100 b, p797.ages d  is expensive. Do you have spatial indexes on b.geom and d.geom. ..http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html

Comment: geom's and hex_id's have indexes, yes. I am sure there are better ways to code this to make it more efficient... please!

Comment: Sorry I've overseen ..Geoms and Hex_ID's are indexed. Could you test ST_SnapToGrid to prevent rounding errors http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_SnapToGrid.html

Comment: First, update all unvalid geoms to make them valid. Try make_valid() after st_intersection: st_makevalid(st_intersection(b.geom, d.geom))...

Comment: Also, with coords in err message, you can isolate an error for better testing...

Comment: Per WKT'S advice, st_intersection can often return invalid geometries so run make_valid after the intersection. If your input tables have invalid geoms then I'd clean them up before doing anything outside of your query.